# PUTTY X11 Forwarding does not work: no DISPLAY variable set

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, putty, xauth

I want to get a GUI to an ubuntu server. Locally, I installed XMING & PUTTY and enabled the `X11 forwarding`. I also tried to specifically set the display location to `localhost:0`, because I read that it could be helpful. Unfortunately, after watching multiple youtube tutorials and reading through dozens of guides, I simply cannot get it to work. Whenever I connect to the server, the `DISPLAY` variable is not initialized. I did the following:

- enable X11Forwarding in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- install `xauth` on the server
- try manually setting the `DISPLAY` variable to :0.0, =:0, =:1 etc.

Does anyone know how to fix or debug this properly?

EDIT: I **might** know the issue: I can only login to the server as root account! Could that maybe cause the problem?

---

Comment: You installed XMING, but is it running? You said you enabled X11 forwarding in `ssh_config` (OpenSSH client config, irrelevant as you're using PuTTY) and in `sshd_config` (but did you restart `sshd` afterwards?), but it's unclear if you ticked the checkbox for X11 forwarding in the PuTTY configuration.

Comment: Yes to all of them - I read in a forum that X11 doesn't work when connected as root. Unfortunately, I am somehow permitted to assign sudo rights to non-root users .. it's a company server

Comment: The fact that the DISPLAY variable is not getting initialized automatically might mean the filesystem containing the target user's home directory on the remote host is 100% full, so the `~/.Xauthority` file cannot be generated by `xauth` and so the X11 forwarding attempt fails. Do you see any error messages from `xauth` when logging in with X11 forwarding enabled?

Comment: no I don't get any error message - only a notification that I am using `ubuntu-minimal`, but I guess that should be no issue?

Comment: You said  "I am somehow permitted to assign sudo rights to non-root users"... that would be the expected state of affairs when logged in as root. Was there a "not" missing from that sentence? If you are logged in as root but are prevented from configuring `sudo` and unable to login as non-root, that sounds like the server might have already been hacked and rootkitted (possibly many times over), and any strange behavior might be the results of inexpert hacking.

Comment: If it's a company server, it might also been "hardened" by the previous administrator, typically by disabling or removing any services and software components that are not essential to the task the system is supposed to perform. That might mean the server has no X11 GUI libraries installed, and so no X11 GUI application can run successfully on it.